# How can I teleport a player to a location relative to another player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to teleport a player to a location relative to another. For example, I might want to teleport *Steve* so that he's exactly 50 blocks on top of *Joe*.

I can't use `/tp`, since that will teleport Steve directly onto Joe's location. Is there a way I can teleport someone to somebody else's location, but with an offset? I'd like to do this with a single command, if possible.

Answer (score 6):

The `/tp` command accepts relative arguments (~), but you won't be able to do it in a single command. You may wish to use a pair of command blocks to execute them quickly and more or less seamlessly.

The following will teleport Steve to Joe, then zero blocks forward (in the x direction), fifty blocks up (in the y direction), and zero blocks to the side (in the z direction).

```
/tp Steve Joe
/tp Steve ~ ~50 ~
```

The format is as follows:

```
 /tp [player] <x> <y> <z> [<y-rot> <x-rot>]
```

More information can be found on the Official Minecraft wiki:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#teleport

Answer (score 2):

execute Joe ~ ~ ~ teleport Steve ~ ~50 ~

for teleport command, the relative coordinate is of the executor, but not the teleported entity.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute positioned as Joe run teleport Steve ~ ~50 ~` (/tp could also work, because tp and teleport are the same command in 1.13)

Answer (score 0):

```
/execute Joe ~ ~50 ~ /tp Steve @p
```

`execute` will make `Joe` execute it but the `~ ~50 ~` would make it execute 50 blocks above Joe's feet because relatives (~) on entities alway count from the bottom block (that is the case with blocks sometimes too, ie. doors and two-block plants). `Steve` is the parameter which tells the game who to teleport.

Answer (score -1):

```
/execute Joe ~ ~50 ~ /tp Steve @p
```

Comment: Do you think you could add some explanation of the syntax you're using?

Answer (score -2):

You can do the following:

```
/execute Joe ~ ~ ~ /tp Steve ~ ~50 ~
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: While it seems like it should work, it doesn't. The tp commands coordinates are always relative to the entity being teleported, not relative to the coordinates the command is executed at. This command is no different from Joe typing `/tp Steve ~ ~50 ~` in his chat.

Answer (score -3):

Well, you could teleport with coordinates.

> /tp username (or @p, @a ect if you are making a custom map) x y z

XYZ are available to you when you press f3.